# JAVA aws s3client : throwing exception : java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect to my s3 bucket ( already created and I am able to test by listing using s3cmd ) and list the contest of it.

Not seeing any error message when trying to create the connection. However, **when trying to list the the content of my bucket**, I am getting the **exception** :

```
java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: bootstrap method initialization exception
```

I am using the dependency ( in gradle) :

```
implementation "software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.7.10"
```

Here the code snippet (**I am getting the above error from** : adapterSmsS3Client.listBuckets())

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

....

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "adapter-stream/dev";

....

S3Client adapterSmsS3Client = S3Client.builder()
        .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
        .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(AwsBasicCredentials.create("access-key","secret-key")))
        .endpointOverride(URI.create(BASE_URL))
        .build();
System.out.println("====Checking connection:  " +adapterSmsS3Client.listBuckets());
```

Any insight on what I am missing ?

Comment: read this documentation and get your solution. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-buckets.html

Comment: how to list objects located in a given bucket https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/ListObjects.java

Comment: This documentation did not help in my case, as it was a version conflict issue, not an issue with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone encountering this, in my case it was due to a version upgrade required for httpcore. Upgrading from 4.4.8 to 4.4.9 solved this for me.

I'm using

```
implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 'aws-sdk-java', version: '2.17.56'
```

build.gradle change:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.9'
```

Related stackoverflow: [java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception from Athena java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265959/java-lang-bootstrapmethoderror-call-site-initialization-exception-from-athena-j)